# Some question of reassembling TCP stream

Tags: http, tcp

I'm implementing an IPS system, and I'm a little confused when observing the procesure of TCP stream reassembling by wireshark.

For example, the server transfer a HTML page to the client. The page is divided into 4 parts and encapsulated by TCP packet. Then the server push another 4 TCP packets to the client for a JavaScript text.

My question is, I know I can determine their sequences by measuring their Seq and Len, but how can I determine the end of the HTML text? How can I know the HTML contains 4 TCP packets but not 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 2616 section 4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) states that the message length could be given in several ways:

- By the `Content-Length` header if one is defined. (This is probably the case you're seeing, and it's relatively simple. If you know the position (seq+offset within packet) of the start of body and the message length, you can just add to get the position of the end.)
- By chunked encoding. The RFC has the details, but it has a similar encoding for each chunk and a way of noting the final chunk.
- `multipart/byteranges` (which you won't see unless the client asked for it, and it probably won't for an HTML document).
- Or until the TCP connection is closed. (In particular, until a `FIN` packet is sent from the server to the client, which only happens on a clean close; you'd see an `RST` otherwise.)

Comment: It's implicit in the answer, but I'd like to make it explicit: Except for closing the TCP connection (which is the only option in HTTP/1.0, by the way), it will *always* require some knowledge of the HTTP protocol itself. I.e. information gleamed from the TCP/IP headers is *not* sufficient for this.